# ECONNABORTED when attempting to connect ESP32 and ESP8266

Tags: python, sockets, esp8266, esp32, micropython

I'm attempting to connect an ESP32 and ESP8266 via sockets with micropython. I cannot get the ESP8266 client to connect to the ESP32 server without throwing an ECONNABORTED 103 error. Code is below, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This seems to work when working off of my laptop and had no issues until trying to connect these two specific devies.

ESP32 Server Code:

```
import network
import socket
from time import sleep

SSID = 'esp'
KEY = 'meow'
ADDR = '192.168.4.1'
PORT = 2000

class socket_master:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind(('',PORT))
        self.attempt = 0
    
    def accept_connection(self):
        self.sock.listen(4)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
    
    def test_speed(self):
        data = 'attempt ' + str(self.attempt)
        self.conn.sendall(data.encode())
        self.attempt += 1


attempt = 0
try:
    print('starting network')
    ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    print('network started')
    if ap.active() == False:
        ap.active(True)
    sleep(1)
    ap.config(essid='esp')
    print(ap.config('essid'))
    print('set ssid')
    print(ap.ifconfig())

except:
    print('failed')

sm = socket_master()
sm.accept_connection()
print('waiting for client')
while True:
    sm.test_speed()
```

ESP8266 Client Code:

```
# main.py -- put your code here!
import network
import socket

SSID = 'esp'
KEY = 'meow'
ADDR = '192.168.4.1'
PORT = 2000

def do_connect():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        wlan.connect('esp')
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            pass
    print('network config:', wlan.ifconfig())

class socket_master_2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((ADDR,PORT))

    def receive_print(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        print(data.decode())


do_connect()
client = socket_master_2()
while True:
    client.receive_print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when Micropython is installed on the ESP8266 it automatically creates an access point, and I believe that when the CLIENT attempts to create a STATION and connect with the SERVER, the AP that MicroPython automatically creates for the 8266 on the CLIENT board conflicts with the STN I created and want to use.

I added the following to my boot.py on the CLIENT board to forcefully takeover the AP and then close it. My CLIENT immediately connected after reboot.

```
wlan = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.config(essid='MicroTemp')
wlan.active(False)
```

I first tried to simply add: `wlan.active(False)` to boot.py but that didn't work.